# Weird runtime error

Tags: c++

I am having trouble running my very bare c++ program. It is a BigInt class that takes in a string as input and sets each individual number into a dynamic array. All I am trying to do so far is input a BigInt and then output it...very simple. My program compiles and runs just fine but once I enter my first input it gives me this weird error..."This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

I am not sure what to do about this problem seeing that I cannot find any flaws in my code.

Anyone have any ideas?

Heres my code:

HEADER FILE:

```
#ifndef BIGINT_H
#define BIGINT_H

#include <iostream>

namespace JHall{
class BigInt {
public:
    BigInt(std::string s = "");
    BigInt(const BigInt& b);
    ~BigInt();
    void operator =(const BigInt& b);
    friend std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, BigInt& b);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const BigInt& b);

private:
    short* num;
    int cap;
    int size;

};
}
#endif  /* BIGINT_H */
```

IMPLEMENTATION FILE:

```
#include "BigInt.h"
#include <cstdlib>

namespace JHall{
BigInt::BigInt(std::string s) 
{
    size = s.length();
    cap = 100;
    num = new short[cap];
    int place = 0;
    for(int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        num[place++] = strtol(s.substr(i-1,1).c_str(), NULL, 10);
}

BigInt::BigInt(const BigInt& b) 
{
    size = b.size;
    cap = b.cap;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        num[i] = b.num[i];
}

BigInt::~BigInt() 
{
    delete [] num;
}

void BigInt::operator =(const BigInt& b)
{
    if(cap != b.cap)
    {
        short* temp = new short[b.cap];
        for(int i = 0; i < b.cap; i++)
            temp[i] = b.num[i];
        delete [] num;
        num = temp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
        num[i] = b.num[i];

    size = b.size;
    cap = b.cap;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, BigInt& b)
{
    std::string s;
    in>>s;
    b.size = s.length();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = b.size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        b.num[count++] = strtol(s.substr(i-1,1).c_str(),NULL,10);
    return in;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const BigInt& b)
{
    for(int i = b.size-1; i >= 0; i--)
        out<<b.num[i];
    return out;
}

}
```

MAIN FILE:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "BigInt.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace JHall;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    BigInt b1, b2;
    cout<<"Enter a large integer"<<endl;
    cin>>b1;
    cout<<"Enter another large integer"<<endl;
    cin>>b2;

    cout<<b1;
    cout<<b2;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, run it in the debugger and see where it breaks.

Comment: It breaks when it hits my first cin>>b1; I'm not quite sure why because I've properly overloaded the >> operator to read my BigInt

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
for(int i = b.size-1; i >= 0; i--)
    b.num[count++] = strtol(s.substr(i-1,1).c_str(),NULL,10);
```

At i equals zero you are asking for a substring starting at -1.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious error is that you don't allocate memory in the copy constructor: if this is every used, you'll most likely get a crash. Another, relatively obvious error, is that you assume that there will be at most 100 digits which seems to be an unnecessary limitation. The assignment operator seems to to do unnecessary work in typically copying the values twice. Also, converting an individual digit from a `char` to a `short` using substrings and `strtol()` seems a bit overkill. The proper way is to use

```
int value = s[i] - '0';
```

Also, you should consider using the member initializer list in you constructors. Of course, if you have a working copy constructor, you might want to also implement a `swap()` method and then use this in your assignment operator:

```
BigInt& BigInt::operetor= (BigInt const& other) {
    BigInt(other).swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for these helpful observations. I will certainly fix my code according to what you said. I'm very intrigued by how you assigned that integer value to the character. I have never seen this and wasn't aware this was even possible, thanks a lot!

Comment: May I ask how exactly that works? (assigning the character to the integer)

Comment: `char` are just integers. `'0'` is the base value of the sequence of digits, i.e. the other digits are guaranteed to have values in sequence starting at `'0'`. That is, `'1' == '0' + 1`, `'2' == '0' + 2`, etc. You can take advantage of it by the obvious transformation: `1 == '1' - '0'`, etc.

Comment: My mistake I meant assigning the integer to a character...same difference. In addition I replaced my substrings and strtol() with your idea and it did not quite work correctly. When I enter 12345 as my BigInt, I get 254492345 as my output.

Comment: When it should be 54321 since I am storing them backwards.

Comment: I'd think it worked: the last for digits are from the string and whatever is in front of it is a random number probably found in the array by chance: print the digits with a separator and you'll see what I mean. I'm not sure how you loops look like but you now seem to not process the first digits. You want something along the lines of `for (size_t i(b.size); i--; ) b.num[count++] = s[i] - '0';` That things aren't reversed is down to reversing the order again upon output.

Comment: Nevermind it works, I just had some coding errors that made it wrong. Thanks so much again this will be very useful in coding to come!

Comment: Of course, it works! The standard guarantees it (in 2.3 [lex.charset] paragraph 3: "... In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous. ...".